# cannot install qtbase5-dev due to unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, ubuntu-gnome

I need to install qtbase5-dev but

```
$> sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qtbase5-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev or
                        libgles2-dev but it is not installable
```

I traced it down to:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwayland-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwayland-dev : Depends: libwayland-client0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-server0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-cursor0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have a mint condition (nearly ~24h without any manual changes only apt-get install) ubuntu-gnome 14.04.2 installed.

As I need to be able to use pyqt5, which depends on qt5-default, which depends on gt5base-dev I was wondering **how I can fix this situation?**

*Can I install old versions of packages?*

Comment: Please reff this link and add more information http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'fixed' the problem by installing an 'old' ubuntu 14.04 (no .2) - the problem does not occur anymore.